# How to disable repair prompt when opening Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I accidentally ran Visual Studio repair and cancelled it immediately.
Now, I am getting the following prompt whenever I open Visual Studio:

[image]

I don't have any issue with VS if I continue.

How can i disable this?

Comment: Just run the repair and let it finish. It won't do any harm.

Comment: @DavidPostill :) Indeed, I did that. I was not stuck, but I was wondering if I could have saved some time. Thank you.

Comment: There are some files in an incomplete state. Whether they are necessary for the software to function is unknown, but the application is flagged as being an incomplete install. The best thing to do is to allow the repair to complete.